# How to get the last error from MySQL in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am using DBI in Perl to access MySQL.

```
return DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:MyBase:localhost', 'user', 'pass');
…
my $query = $connection->prepare($command);
my $result = $query->execute();
$query->finish;
```

I would like to be able to not use die or try.  I would just like to be able to execute a MySQL command and then on the next call check for error types.

Is this possible?

Comment: That is the default behavior. You need to set RaiseError to cause exceptions to occur. This is highly recommended, since otherwise people write code like you did with no error checking, and without it you *must* check every call, including connect.

Comment: @Grinnz This is what I want to do.  But "how" do I check for errors?

Comment: As a side note, consider [DBD::MariaDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::MariaDB) if this is new code; it is a fork that avoids issues that are unfixable in DBD::mysql due to backcompat (and supports both MySQL and MariaDB despite the name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented for [connect](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect):

"If the connect fails (see below), it returns undef and sets both $DBI::err and $DBI::errstr. (It does not explicitly set $!.) You should generally test the return status of connect and print $DBI::errstr if it has failed."

Once you have a handle, the [err](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#err) method must be checked after each database or statement handle method call, and [errstr](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#errstr) similarly represents the error message in the event of an error.

It is highly recommended, and indeed required by wrappers such as [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) or [Mojo::Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Pg), to set [RaiseError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) so that you avoid this code clutter and the chance that you will forget to check for errors.

Comment: To turn on use of exceptions: `DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:MyBase:localhost', 'user', 'pass', { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0, PrintWarn => 1 });` (`PrintError => 0` makes it so you don't get duplicate messages, and might as well turn on warnings with `PrintWarn => 1`).

Comment: Thanks @Grinnz this was exactly what I was looking for.  Just as I couldn't find this via Google, I can't seem to find a page listing of all the possible DBI err values.  If you happen to have a link handy would be much appreciated.

Comment: @DanielKaplan These values are up to each driver. All you can really depend on is that a true return from `err` means that an error occurred and `errstr` contains the message.